# Why would there be 4 identical A and AAAA records?

Tags: redirects, dns, cloudflare, google-domains, a-record

I am transferring a domain from Google Domains to Cloudflare.  When recreating the DNS records in Cloudflare, I saw that there are 4 identical A records (with the same IP) and 4 identical AAAA records.  What would be the purpose of that?  This is a domain with a permanent redirect.  It receives email, but is just an alias for web traffic.

Comment: Please give the name. DNS specifications prohibit duplicates, so you can't have multiple records with the exact same data on the exact same name. RFC2181 §5 "It
   is meaningless for two records to ever have label, class, type and
   data all equal - servers should suppress such duplicates if
   encountered.". This becomes mandatory for DNSSEC operations.

Answer (score 1):

Having multiple A (for IPV4) and AAAA (for IPV6) facilitates load balancing by using round-robin DNS - This would be the primary use case.   It also opens the possibility for apps/OS's to build in failover [ ie if the app can't connect to the IP it gets back it can try the lookup process again and may get a different address ].

Comment: But several  A records with the same value?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller  I missed that.   Yeah, I can't see anything other then extremely impractically contrived scenarios where that would be useful  (around playing with TTL). preparing for load balancing in near future.   Sounds like a programming error to me.

Comment: @davidgo thank you - programming error was my suspicion.  Some other process that was done three times auto-generated them. I deleted them with no issues that I have found.